# Chasing game in C

Tags: c, backtracking, branch-and-bound

I'm stuck with a quite complex problem:

> On an *MxN* field containing a chicken, an eagle and a yard, 
>   the chicken tries to escape the eagle (by entering the yard), 
>   and the eagle tries to catch the chicken. The chicken escapes
>    when reaches inside the yard, and the eagle catches the chicken
>    when it's in the same position as the chicken. In a single step,
>    the eagle can move one or two small squares, and the chicken can
>    move a single square in any direction. The program should display 
>   a message saying if the chicken can win. It should compute the moves,
>    and, at each step, it should write in the output file the current
>    configuration of the field, and it should also visually represent 
>   it on the screen. The dimensions of the field, position of the chicken 
>   and of the eagle, and also of the yard, are given in a file.

I've solved the part with creating the field (a matrix), but I can't figure it out how to solve this. Perhaps backtracking would be an idea, but it's very complicated, and I can't handle it. I think I should find a way to find out the distance between the chicken and the yard, also between the eagle and the yard, and work somehow with that. It has to be in C. Any suggestion, idea is welcomed!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Smells like homework. Why not get a bird brain (chicken and or Eagle) to do it?

Comment: For a complex problem like this, it often helps to work through the problem a few times by hand, just to get a sense of what decisions need to be made to move the chicken and the eagle on each turn. Once you have a better idea of how each of them make decisions, you can start to formalize them in code.

Comment: This question really isn't suitable for SO, but maybe you'd get somewhere by considering shortest paths of the two birds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an interesting problem. Let's go over the rules again. Players

1. Chicken: takes shortest path to field (there could be multiple shortest paths) and away from eagle (maximise the distance between itself and eagle among shortest paths).
2. Eagle: takes shortest path to chicken

To solve the problem we have to assume it is played in turns: first chicken then eagle and so on.
Game is over when :

1. Eagle is on chicken.
2. Chicken is on field.

Here is the trick for the distance:

**Update**

The distance you want is called [Chebyshev distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance). You can easily calculate it:

`distance = max of(difference of corresponding coordinates between the two points)`

For (1,1) and (2,3) distance = max(|1-2|,|2-3|) = 2

For (2,3) and (4,7) distance = 4

For (4,5,6) and (1,1,1) distance = 5

You can ignore the older answer if you want.

---

**Old**

`distance = Manhattan distance - length of longest 45 deg diagonal`

Manhattan distance is easy to understand. See its [wiki](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance). Take some examples :

```
    ---/F
    --/-|
    -/--|
    C---X

    manhattan distance = 7
    length of max diagonal = 3
    distance = 7-3 = 4
```

Another one

```
    ---/-F
    --/--|
    -/---|
    C----X

    distance = 8-3 = 5
```

**Caveat**: Remember there can be many shortest possible paths. For eg.

```
    ---F
    --/F
    -/-F
    C--F
    -\-F
    --\F
    ---F
```

Lots of places to go in 3 moves. Pick one which is farthest from eagle using distance calculator.
Also if distance between eagle and chicken is less than chicken and field at any time then eagle wins else chicken. Just simulate the moves and you will know.